# How to implement a right navbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navbar

The flutter scaffold shows a right navbar, but I suppose there is no right nav widget. How do I implement a right navbar with scaffold in flutter?

[Flutter Scaffold Image](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0Bx4BSt6jniD7T0hfM01sSmRyTG8/layout_structure_regions_mobile.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Scaffold`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) now has a [`endDrawer`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/endDrawer.html) property which swipes from right-to-left.

Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to show a right bar/menu or `Drawer` in your app, whether it is has a permanent view or a temporary one. I was able to achieve this by building my own custom widget from `Allign`, `Container` and `Column` widgets, and by using `setState` to show or hide the menu bar based on user interaction, see this simple example.

[image]

**My custom menu widget looks like the following:**

```
class RightNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RightNavigationBarState createState() => new _RightNavigationBarState();
}

class _RightNavigationBarState extends State<RightNavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Align(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.centerRight,
      child: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
            new Icon(Icons.close),
            new Text ("More items..")
          ],
        ),
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        height: 700.0,
        width: 200.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Then when the user presses the menu `icon`, an object of my custom `RightNavigationBar` widget is created inside `setState` :**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _myRightBar = null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          actions: [new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon (Icons.menu), onPressed: _showRightBar)
          ],
          title: new Text("Right Navigation Bar Example"),
        ),
        body: _myRightBar

    );
  }

  _showRightBar() {
    setState(() {
      _myRightBar == null
          ? _myRightBar = new RightNavigationBar()
          : _myRightBar = null;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**vertical_navigation_bar**

How to use it? #

Install

```
 dependencies:
  vertical_navigation_bar: ^0.0.1
```

Run flutter command

```
flutter pub get
```

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vertical_navigation_bar/vertical_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Abubakr Elghazawy (Software Developer)',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: 0,
      keepPage: true
  );

  final navItems = [
    SideNavigationItem(icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calendarCheck, title: "New task"),
    SideNavigationItem(icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calendarAlt, title: "Personal task"),
    SideNavigationItem(icon: FontAwesomeIcons.fileAlt, title: "Personal document"),
    SideNavigationItem(icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calendar, title: "Company task"),
    SideNavigationItem(icon: FontAwesomeIcons.arrowCircleRight, title: "Options")
  ];
  final initialTab = 0;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SideNavigation(
            navItems: this.navItems,
            itemSelected: (index){
              pageController.animateToPage(
                  index,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  curve: Curves.linear
              );
            },
            initialIndex: 0,
            actions: <Widget>[

            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              itemCount: 5,
              controller: pageController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Container(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.1),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Page " + index.toString()),
                    )
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More Dtails[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/vertical_navigation_bar)

Answer (score 0):

Use the **endDrawer** property of the **Scaffold** like this:

```
   Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          endDrawer: const SideBar(),
          body: CustomScrollView(
```